# Constexpr tricks

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, constexpr

I think it's not possible but I'd like to ask you before give up about it.

I want something like a constexpr increment.

```
#include  <iostream>

constexpr int inc() {

  static int inc = 0;
  return inc++;
}

class Foo {

  static const int  Type = inc();
};

class Foo2 {

  static const int  Type = inc();
};

int main() {

  std::cout << "Foo1 " << Foo1::Type << st::endl;
  std::cout << "Foo2 " << Foo2::Type << st::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I want to call it into some classes **not manually** (I use CRTP for that), to give a different type to each of them, but the type need to be const.
There is anyway to achieve something like that in C++? (C++17 + TS)

Comment: *"I think it's not possible"* Basically everything is possible with C++ templates, it just gets stupidly complex sometimes.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it might be part of C++17, but I may be wrong

Comment: There are non-standard `COUNTER` macros, and there are implementations of compile-time side-effects ([Filip Roseen](http://b.atch.se/) comes to mind). The latter are extremely ugly, though. I'd rather try a different approach.

Comment: If you don't need contiguity, just use the address of some object as a unique identifier.

Comment: Have fun with this madness: http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/

*(please don't do this)*

Comment: @dyp Infortunatly I need them to be contiguous (I use them as index). Thanks for your link, I don't want a perfect solution, something working is already crazy. Maybe one day C++ will allow that but I can't wait for now.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo I know this is ugly, but if I do it only one time in a specific header, I think it will be ok (this counter is a logic base of my library).

Comment: Can you live with a type list like `type_list<Foo, Foo2>` explicitly mentioning all the types you want to have counter for?

Comment: @dyp I just need the final value, so don't worry the ugly code will stay there.

Comment: @dyp do you know the clang version of this things by any chance?

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel The clang version of what?

Comment: @dyp of the constant-expression counter. But I think I'll give up, is just to risky for a base that I'll use in every project. Nobody can say if it will work everywhere (even clang can't).

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel The MSVC-workaround won't work with clang at all currently, because of https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15481 The original, non-MSVC-workaround version should work though AFAIK.

Comment: @dyp well I have a hard time thinking about this. Do you think it's safe to use in production code? I won't touch it, and it will have a separate header, but still seems dangerous to use a hack.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel Production code?? I would strongly advise **NOT** to use this in production code. It might break when updating a compiler version, and then it's really hard to fix, or even impossible. With MSVC and clang, you'd also have to maintain two versions of it. There's been some discussions about if this thing is even conforming to the C++ standard on the publi C++ Standard Discussion Mailing List...

Comment: @dyp Well I had already give up about using it in production code. But your comment reassure me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is the solution by [Filip Roseen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090079/filip-ros%C3%A9en-refp) called the [constant-expression counter](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/):

```
#include  <iostream>

template<int N>
struct flag {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>);
};

template<int N>
struct writer {
  friend constexpr int adl_flag (flag<N>) {
    return N;
  }

  static constexpr int value = N;
};

template<int N, int = adl_flag (flag<N> {})>
int constexpr reader (int, flag<N>) {
  return N;
}

template<int N>
int constexpr reader (float, flag<N>, int R = reader (0, flag<N-1> {})) {
  return R;
}

int constexpr reader (float, flag<0>) {
  return 0;
}

template<int N = 1>
int constexpr next (int R = writer<reader (0, flag<32> {}) + N>::value) {
  return R;
}

class Foo {

  public:
    static const int  Type = next();
};

class Foo2 {

  public:
    static const int  Type = next();
};

int main() {

  std::cout << "Foo1 " << Foo::Type << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Foo2 " << Foo2::Type << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks guys :)
**But it's too risky for use it in my main library which will be use in every project.**

PS: I won't close this right now if there is another answer. Because yes it's ugly.